# How to find the domain of the of distribution function Y=g(X)=|X| from X density function?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Given:

$
f_X(x) =
\begin{cases}
1/3,  & -1 \leq x \leq 2 \\
0, & else \\
\end{cases}
$

$
F_X(x) =
\begin{cases}
0,  & x < -1 \\
\frac{x+1}{3}, & -1 \leq x \leq 2\\
1, & x > 2 \\
\end{cases}
$

$
Y=g(X)=|X|
$

How to find the domain of the of distribution function $F_Y(y)$ from the above information?

My teacher draw a $Y=g(X)$ graph and concluded from there the domain of $F_Y(y)$,
but I don't understand the steps for that, I will be happy to get explanation.

Comment: Shouldn't $F_X(x)$ be between 0 and 1?

Comment: I corrected the question

Answer (score 0):

$F_Y(y) = p(Y \leq y) = p (|X| \leq y)$, which means that $F_Y(y) = 0$ for negative $y$

For non-negative $y$:  $p(|X|\leq y) = p ( -y \leq X \leq y)
= p (X < y) - p(X< -y) = F_X(y) - F_X (-y)$.

$$
F_Y(y) = 
\left\{
\begin{array}[lll]\\
0 & when & y \leq 0\\
\frac{2y}{3} & when & 0\leq y < 1\\
\frac{y+1}{3}& when & 1 \leq y \leq 2\\
1 & when & y > 2
\end{array}
\right.
$$
The density function has constant values of 0, 2/3, 1/3, 0 respectively for those intervals.

Comment: why you split the domain to $ 0\leq x < 1\\ $  and  $ 1 \leq x \leq 2\\ $ in $F_Y(y)$ and how did you found his domain at all?

Comment: @Yakir  by computing $F_X(y) - F_X (-y)$.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand, I will be happy for more deeper explanation and If you can calculate it step by step.

Comment: @Yakir I fixed typos in my answer where I used $y$ on the left hand side and $x$ on the right hand side.  Since you know formulas for  $F_X(x)$ can you figure out formulas for $F_X(x) - F_X(-x)$ ?

Comment: Yes but this is not my problem in your solution. How did you infer the splitting point in the domain of $F_Y(y)$? that what I don't understand.

Comment: @Yakir Have you tried writing down expression for $F_X(x) - F_X(-x)$ ?

Comment: No because I don't know the domain X run on.
Can you elaborate on the steps please?

Comment: @Yakir  Domain of $X$ or domain of $F_X$ ? If the latter, the domains of both $F_X$ and $F_Y$ are $(-\infty, \infty)$. If you are talking about sub-intervals in the above formulas, then $F_X$ inherits them from the density function $f_X$, and for $F_Y$ they become obvious once you actually try to figure out the formulas for $F_X(x) - F_X(-x)$